# How do i make switch and if statement in one function

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
function texas(val) {
    var answer = "";
    switch(val) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            var answer = "low";
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            var answer = "medium";
            break;
    } else if(val =>  7) {
        var answer = "Huge"
    }
    return answer;
}
```

it says error Declaration or statement expected. ts(1128) [13, 7]
and it poits at the else if statement

Comment: else if cannot be used without if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `>=` and the `else`has to be deleted. The `var`for answer is unnecesary, just declare it once with `let`. You forgot the `break` in `case 3:`.

```js
function texas(val) {
    let answer = "";
    switch(val) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            answer = "low";
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            answer = "medium";
            break;
    }
    if(val >=  7) {
        answer = "Huge"
    }
    return answer;
}

console.log(texas(2));
console.log(texas(8));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "default" keyword, but you should probably update your code in order to handle the cases in which the value of the parameter is not positive or not a number:

```
function texas(val) {

    if (val <= 0 || isNan(val)) {
       throw new InvalidOperationException("val should be a positive number");
    }


    switch(val) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            return "low";
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
           return "medium";
        default:
            return "Huge"
    }
}
```

Comment: And probably best to remove the unnecessary `var`s in the `switch`.

Comment: This code wont work. What about val="notEvenAnumber". It will return huge but val is not more or equal to 7.

Comment: You can use ```switch(true)``` in order to avoid ```case``` repeating.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return in the switch

```
function texas(val) {
    var answer = "";
    switch(val) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            var answer = "low";
            return answer;
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            var answer = "medium";
 
            return answer;
    }
     if(val =>  7) {
        var answer = "Huge"
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an `if` statement within a `switch` block.

You do have the `default` option tho -

```
function texas(val) {
var answer = "";
switch(val) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
       answer = "low";
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
       answer = "medium";
       break;
    default:
       answer = val >= 7 ? "Huge" : "Invalid";
       break;
}
return answer;
```

Note that if you have a minus / negative answer, it'll also fall into this clause, but you can the the value of `answer` with an inline `?:` if statement...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax does not allow to put an `else` after a `switch`. `else` only makes sense in combination with an `if` statemen. But `switch` has a `default:` case which most closely matches your intention (hopefully):

```
function texas(val) {
    var answer = "";
    switch(val) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            var answer = "low";
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            answer = "medium";
            break;
        default:
            if(val >= 7) {
              answer = "Huge"
            }

            // decide what should happen if val is 0, -1 or not even a number (e.g. texas('gotcha!')
            break;
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Don't forget to put `break` in your cases, otherwise execution will "fall through" and execute the next cases. You would never end up with `"low"`

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the `else` after the `switch` block as people have stated above. `switch` statement is better for multi way branching and fixed data values. On the other side, `if` statement is better for boolean values. You can do something like this. It might not be the shortest line of codes, but just so you that there's another approach:

```
function texas(val) {
    let answer = "";
    switch (true) {
        case (val == 1 || val == 2 || val == 3):
            answer = "low";
            break;
        case (val == 4 || val == 5 || val == 6):
            answer = "medium";
            break;
        case (val >= 7):
            answer = "huge";
            break;
    }
    return answer;
}
```